# Calling a method from another jar file

Tags: java, jar

I'm still kind of new to java, and one thing I haven't had to work with until now is calling a method from a class that is not in a package that is part of that particular project. I have two jars: ai.jar and functions.jar. Inside functions.jar I have a bunch of classes right inside, so they aren't in folders or anything. Inside ai.jar, I have a class that accesses a particular method inside ai.jar. I've tried to create a reference variable by using `functions.jar/get.class` and various other things like that, but I always get a classnotfoundexception. How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: The jar file simply needs to be in your [class path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29).  How you do that depends on what environment you're using.  With the "bare" java/javac commands you use the -classpath parm or set the CLASSPATH environment variable.  In an IDE you use whatever the IDE wants.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add them to your `Build path`  of your project.

Then you just need to `import` that `class`.

Then create the instance of particular `class` if it is a `instance` method.

Other wise `ClassnameInJar.method();`  if it is a `static` class.

[See examples with screen shots](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29)

Answer (score 4):

I assume you want to import a jar into your project, for that the instructions are presented below:

1. Step 1. Right click on your project
2. Step 2. Select "Build Path"
3. Step 3. Then select "Configure Build Path"
4. Step 4. Select "Add external jar", then browse to the location of
   your desired jar.

Hope it helps.